# GoogleSQL query does not return expected results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Long story short, I am currently building tables for multiple advertiser accounts, and at the start of my script I create multiple temporary tables based on different conditions to decide the execution flow for each account, i.e. a profile id will fall into any one of the tables and go thorugh the flow assigned to that table.

However, I am currently having problems with the determinant condition of one of my temp tables.

Below is the code for creating the temp table in question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE new_id_with_ad_conv_only as (
select distinct profile_id, concat('campaign_acct_',profile_id,'_',REGEXP_REPLACE(profile, r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", '_')) as table_name from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_nodevice_metrics` left join (select * except(date) from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.account_info`) using (profile_id) where profile_id in (select distinct profile_id from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.ad_nodevice_conversions` where date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')-14 AND CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong') group by profile_id having string_agg(conversion_tracker_id) is not null) and profile_id not in (select distinct profile_id from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_nodevice_conversions` left join (select * except(date) from  `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_info`) using(campaign_id) where advertising_channel_type="Performance Max" and date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')-14 AND CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')) and profile_id not in (SELECT distinct profile_id FROM `gads-supermetrics.merge_campaign.campaign_acct_*`) and date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')-14 AND CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong'));
```

The above code is basically selecting profile_id and a custom-created field named table_name (concatenating "campaign_acct_", profile_id and profile) from a table resulting from the left-joining of campaign_nodevice_metrics and campaign_info using the column campaign_id. The conditions used are:

1. the profile_id exists in ad_nodevice_conversions in the past 14 days, and the conversion_tracker_ids in ad_nodevice_conversions, when grouped by profile_id, are non-null;
2. the profile_id does not exist in campaign_nodevice_metrics in the past 14 days where the advertising_channel_type is "Performance Max"; and
3. the account does NOT already exist in the dataset 'gads-supermetrics.merge_campaign', i.e.

```
profile_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct profile_id FROM `gads-supermetrics.merge_campaign.campaign_acct_*`)
```

I tried running the the above query, but it returned no results. In an attempt to debug, I tried running the same query excluding condition (3), i.e.:

```
select distinct profile_id, concat('campaign_acct_',profile_id,'_',REGEXP_REPLACE(profile, r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", '_')) as table_name from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_nodevice_metrics` left join (select * except(date) from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.account_info`) using (profile_id) where profile_id in (select distinct profile_id from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.ad_nodevice_conversions` where date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')-14 AND CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong') group by profile_id having string_agg(conversion_tracker_id) is not null) and profile_id not in (select distinct profile_id from `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_nodevice_conversions` left join (select * except(date) from  `gads-supermetrics.all_component_tables_partitioned.campaign_info`) using(campaign_id) where advertising_channel_type="Performance Max" and date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong')-14 AND CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Hong_Kong'))
```

and it returned 73 profile_ids, meaning there should be 73 ids regardless of whether they already exist in the "merge_campaign" dataset.

Afterwards, I tried running a similar query as the original one, the only difference being condition (3) now becomes "the account already exists in the merge_campaign dataset", i.e.

```
profile_id IN (SELECT distinct profile_id FROM `gads-supermetrics.merge_campaign.campaign_acct_*`)
```

and it returned 70 ids in total.

Comparing the results of the two debug queries above, there is a discrepancy of 3 ids between them. So the weird part is, why are there no results returned when I run the original query, which contains condition (3), while 70 ids are returned when I slightly modify the query to contain the inverse of condition (3)? There should be a total of 73 ids when both sides are added up together, since they are mutually exclusive.

Appreciate any helpful insights and suggestions!